# Is it possible to remove the comma that appears before an in-text citation note?

Tags: citing, natbib, punctuation, apacite

I am using natbib and the apacite style. I want to cite Descartes' Meditations, and one standard way of doing it involves an in-text citation of the form '(CSM 25)'. I managed to use the alias system to get '(CSM, 25)', but I don't know how to remove the comma. Is there a way to remove the comma to get '(CSM 25)'? The following is my code for the citation followed by my code for the .bib file:

```
\defcitealias{Meditations}{CSM}
\citepalias[][25]{Meditations}


@book{Meditations,
  author = {Rene Descartes},
  year = {1985},
  title = {The Philosophical Writings of {Descartes}, Vol. 2},
  translator = {John Cottingham and Robert Stoothoff and Dugald Murdoch},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  originalyear = {1641},
  address     = {Cambridge},
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about your document, including the document class , any citation management packages, and the bibliography style you employ. (Aside: the `apacite` bibliography style should be used alongside the `apacite` citation manatement package.) Please also clarify what the number `25` in `\citepalias[][25]{Meditations}` denotes: a page number? something else?

Comment: The document class is 'report'. The citation packages are:
`\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}`

The number 25 is for the section number. It is in the margin and covers 1-2 paragraphs. It is distinct from the page number.

I had to switch to natbib from apacite because apacite wasn't allowing me to do multiple authors in an in-text citation with their own page numbers. I'm sticking to this package now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the `apacite` citation management package with the option `natbibapa`, you can issue a directive such as `\setcitestyle{notesep={ }}` to change the separator between the (aliased) citation callout and the subsequent note.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
% using 'article' rahter than 'report' to keep all output on the same page

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{Meditations,
  author       = {René Descartes},
  year         = {1985},
  title        = {The Philosophical Writings of {Descartes}, {Vol.~2}},
  translator   = {John Cottingham and Robert Stoothoff and Dugald Murdoch},
  publisher    = {Cambridge University Press},
  originalyear = {1641},
  address      = {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\defcitealias{Meditations}{CSM}
\setcitestyle{notesep={ }} % default separator string is ", "

\begin{document}
\citepalias[25]{Meditations}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```